# Insert a dropdown list from database to wordpress page($.post is not function)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, mysqli

it's about 1 week I'm working to insert a dropdown list to my worspress page. 
It's very simple, I have One table with two columns (Nom and Adresse), I want when I select a Name (Nom) from the dropdown list it display the Adresse of the person(Nom).
I succeed to insert the dropdown list with the column (Nom) with the following code :

```
<select class='Nom' name="Nom" id="Nom">
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>

[insert_php]
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "somapam_bd");

 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Nom FROM herboristes");

while($ligne_liste=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$ligne_liste['Nom'].'">'.$ligne_liste['Nom']."</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
[/insert_php]
<div id="txtHint" type="text" name="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

So the next step to display results i get anything, i followed some tutorials but nothing can work with wordrpress.

Actually i tried this and i get the error when i inspect the page ($.post is not  function) :
1- I did add this code to functions.php :

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri().'/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    // pass Ajax Url to script.js
    wp_localize_script('script', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

2- script.js :

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      $('select.Nom').change(function(){
         $.Post ('formdata.php',
            {},
            function(res){
                  $('#txtHint').html(res);

            }

            );
         });
    });
```

3-formdata.php

```
   <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "somapam_bd");

      $q = intval($_GET['Nom']);
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM herboristes where Nom = '".$q."'");

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
     $row['Adresse'];
    echo $row['Adresse'];
       ?>
```

Please I need someone to help me i don't want to lose more time with that.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code pasted there is `$.Post` maybe is a typo but the correct is all in lowercase `$.post`
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

By the way, Are you using two jQuery installations? Why you use jQuery and $ in the same script ?

Comment: Yeah i solve this the error thank you. Yea I used the $ in the first time just i edited it to sovlve the error thank you so much (y)